# JSON payload how to find a key/value equal to a value provided

Tags: javascript, json

In a project which consume an API I receive a JSON payload as follow:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "study": {
      "id": "DEM1",
      "locales": [
        {
          "locale": "en_IT",
          "language": {
            "direction": "ltr"
          }
        },
        {
          "locale": "en_US",
          "language": {
            "direction": "ltr"
          }
        }
      ]}
```

From this JSON I need to find with JS the locale `en_US` and output the `"direction": "ltr"`.

The locale is arriving inside a method where this JSON is get and I need to extract the right part of it which corresponding of the `en_US`.

I got a difficulty how to do that in this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const obj = {
  "data": {
    "study": {
      "id": "DEM1",
      "locales": [
        {
          "locale": "en_IT",
          "language": { "direction": "ltr" }
        },
        {
          "locale": "en_US",
          "language": { "direction": "ltr" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

const { language } = 
  obj?.data?.study?.locales?.find(({ locale }) => locale === "en_US") || {};

console.log(language);
```